# Content of HTTP request body changes after return from FilterChain

Tags: spring-boot, http, spring-mvc, servlets, servlet-filters

I have a filter that logs the request body twice. First I print the request body from the request object and then pass the request and response object to the FilterChain. Then in the finally{} I print again the content of the body in the request object. But the content is not anymore the same. Actually the content at Step-1 is empty and at Step-2 looks better. What does happens?

```
public class RequestAndResponseLoggingFilter extends OncePerRequestFilter {
```

```
@Override
protected void doFilterInternal(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, FilterChain filterChain) throws ServletException, IOException {
    if (isAsyncDispatch(request)) {
        filterChain.doFilter(request, response);
    } else {
        doFilterWrapped(wrapRequest(request), wrapResponse(response), filterChain);
    }
}
```

```
protected void doFilterWrapped(ContentCachingRequestWrapper request, ContentCachingResponseWrapper response, FilterChain filterChain) throws IOException, ServletException {
    try {
            // Step-1: Print the request body (at request time)
            String requestBody = extractRequestBody(request);
            log.info("Request Body: " + requestBody);

            // Pass the request and response object to FilterChain
            filterChain.doFilter(request, response);
    }
    finally {
            // Step-2: Print again the request body (at response time). Do not get the same output as in Step-1.
            String requestBody = extractRequestBody(request);
            log.info("Request Body: " + requestBody);
    }
}
```

```
private static String extractRequestBody(ContentCachingRequestWrapper request) {
            byte[] content = request.getContentAsByteArray();
            if (content.length > 0) {
                return new String(content, request.getContentType());
            }
            return "";
        }
```

```
}
```

I know there could be another Filter or Interceptor that can change it but I don't have a such one. At least not written from me. What is mechanism that changes the request body in the request object during the request processing time? I am using Spring Boot with Spring MVC. My filter extends OncePerRequestFilter from springframework.

Comment: What does extractRequestBody do?

Comment: It just extracts the body content from the request object.

Comment: Show the code please

Comment: The code is in my original post: private static String extractRequestBody(ContentCachingRequestWrapper request) {
            byte[] content = request.getContentAsByteArray();
            if (content.length > 0) {
                return new String(content, request.getContentType());
            }
            return "";
        }

Comment: How does your filter class look like? Why do you use ContentCachingRequestWrapper ?

Comment: I added some more code to my original post. You can now see better how does the filter class looks like. I used ContentCachingRequestWrapper because if the request body being read for first time then the stream will be closed and it could not be possible to be used further in the FilterChain. So the contentCachingRequestWrapper caches the request content and makes it available if someone wants to read it. It extends HttpServletRequestWrapper and is an implementation from the springframework.